# How to implement a Keyword Search in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, search

I am new to SQL programming.

I have a table job where the fields are `id`, `position`, `category`, `location`, `salary range`, `description`, `refno`.

I want to implement a **keyword search** from the front end. The keyword can reside in any of the fields of the above table.

This is the query I have tried but it consist of so many duplicate rows:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.catname
FROM
    job a,
    category b
WHERE
    a.catid = b.catid AND
    a.jobsalrange = '15001-20000' AND
    a.jobloc = 'Berkshire' AND
    a.jobpos LIKE '%sales%' OR
    a.jobloc LIKE '%sales%' OR
    a.jobsal LIKE '%sales%' OR
    a.jobref LIKE '%sales%' OR
    a.jobemail LIKE '%sales%' OR
    a.jobsalrange LIKE '%sales%' OR
    b.catname LIKE '%sales%'
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For a single keyword on VARCHAR fields you can use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

```
SELECT id, category, location
FROM table
WHERE
(
    category LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR location LIKE '%keyword%'
)
```

For a description you're usually better adding a full text index and doing a [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) (MyISAM only):

```
SELECT id, description
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST('keyword1 keyword2')
```

Comment: SELECT a. * , b.catname
FROM job a, categiry b
WHERE a.catid = b.catid
AND a.jobsalrange = '15001-20000'
AND a.jobloc = 'Berkshire'
AND a.jobpos LIKE '%sales%'
OR a.jobloc LIKE '%sales%'
OR a.jobsal LIKE '%sales%'
OR a.jobref LIKE '%sales%'
OR a.jobemail LIKE '%sales%'
OR a.jobsalrange LIKE '%sales%'
OR b.catname LIKE '%sales%'

acualy this is the query I have tried but it consist so many duplicate rows.

Comment: You just need to bracket your ORs:  WHERE a=b AND c=d AND (e LIKE f OR g LIKE i)

Comment: I don't think it's MYISAM only anymore.

Comment: InnoDB fulltext search is supported in MySQL 5.6.4 and above. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: (MyISAM only): comment saved me time trying to do a full text search on innoDB

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    yourtable
WHERE 
    id LIKE '%keyword%' 
    OR position LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR category LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR location LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR description LIKE '%keyword%'
    OR refno LIKE '%keyword%';
```

Comment: SELECT a. * , b.catname FROM job a, categiry b WHERE a.catid = b.catid AND a.jobsalrange = '15001-20000' AND a.jobloc = 'Berkshire' AND a.jobpos LIKE '%sales%' OR a.jobloc LIKE '%sales%' OR a.jobsal LIKE '%sales%' OR a.jobref LIKE '%sales%' OR a.jobemail LIKE '%sales%' OR a.jobsalrange LIKE '%sales%' OR b.catname LIKE '%sales%' acualy this is the query I have tried but it consist so many duplicate rows.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries in table b with the same catid?

Comment: @santanu you need to perform a join to avoid cartesian join (duplicates values) see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 7):

I will explain the method i usally prefer:

First of all you need to take into consideration that for this method you will sacrifice memory with the aim of gaining computation speed.
Second you need to have a the right to edit the table structure.

1) Add a field (i usually call it "digest") where you store all the data from the table.

The field will look like:

**"n-n1-n2-n3-n4-n5-n6-n7-n8-n9" etc..**  where n is a single word

I achieve this using a regular expression thar replaces " " with "-".
This field is the result of all the table data "digested" in one sigle string.

2) Use the LIKE statement %keyword% on the digest field:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE digest LIKE %keyword%
```

you can even build a qUery with a little loop so you can search for multiple keywords at the same time looking like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
 digest LIKE %keyword1% AND 
 digest LIKE %keyword2% AND 
 digest LIKE %keyword3% ...
```

Comment: I like the multiple "LIKE" statements for the tokenized keywords.

Comment: This solution looks more promising. But how can I achieve to show better matching results at the beginning?

Comment: Your solution suits for me very nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, have a keyword table containing the fields:

```
Keyword
Id
Count (possibly)
```

with an index on Keyword. Create an insert/update/delete trigger on the other table so that, when a row is changed, every keyword is extracted and put into (or replaced in) this table.

You'll also need a table of words to not count as keywords (if, and, so, but, ...).

In this way, you'll get the best speed for queries wanting to look for the keywords and you can implement (relatively easily) more complex queries such as "contains Java and RCA1802".

`"LIKE"` queries will work but they won't scale as well.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I wouldn't use the `LIKE` string comparison on the ID field or any other numeric field. It doesn't make sense for a search for ID# "**216**" to return 16**216**, **216**51, 3**216**087, 53**216**68..., and so on and so forth; likewise with salary.

Also, if you want to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, you would use a query string like:

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE `position` LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%') OR ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find another simpler option in a thread here: [Match Against..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column) with a more detail help in [11.9.2. Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

This is just in case someone need a more compact option. This will require to create an Index FULLTEXT in the table, which can be accomplish easily.

Information on how to create Indexes (MySQL): [MySQL FULLTEXT Indexing and Searching](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm)

In the `FULLTEXT` Index you can have more than one column listed, the result would be an SQL Statement with an index named `search`:

```
SELECT *,MATCH (`column`) AGAINST('+keyword1* +keyword2* +keyword3*') as relevance  FROM `documents`USE INDEX(search) WHERE MATCH (`column`) AGAINST('+keyword1* +keyword2* +keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance;
```

I tried with multiple columns, with no luck. Even though multiple columns are allowed in indexes, you still need an index for each column to use with Match/Against Statement.

Depending in your criterias you can use either options.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but what I did to our application is this. Hope this will help someone tho. But it works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM `landmarks` WHERE `landmark_name` OR `landmark_description` OR `landmark_address` LIKE '%keyword'
OR `landmark_name` OR `landmark_description` OR `landmark_address` LIKE 'keyword%' 
OR `landmark_name` OR `landmark_description` OR `landmark_address` LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the most later one contains all the former ones.