# PHP - Search engine ordering by best results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a search engine and I use the following code for my query:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get many results but what i want to get them ordered by best results prior to less coherent results.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL match() against() - order by relevance and column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column)

Comment: Well, I get results with books that contains single words but i would like to get first records matching as many words as possible first. No matter if it is in any column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is drop the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` and order by that `MATCH ... AGAINST ...` since it returns a number that represents relevancy.

```
SELECT * FROM books 
WHERE MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android')
ORDER BY MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android') DESC
```

if you want to see the numbers to have a feel of what the numbers are you can simply select it too like this

```
SELECT *,MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android') as relevancy FROM books 
WHERE MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android')
ORDER BY MATCH(titulo, description) AGAINST ('mark the android') DESC
```