# How set AND condition to ALL columns - php

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

In [MY TABLE](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf1/examples/server_side/simple.html) if I type

```
floor fly
```

table returns `No matching records` because *Global Search* php function search records inside a SINGLE column. 

But I want that AND condition works to ALL columns.

If I type `floor fly` table should me display something like:

```
|__Column1___|___Column2____|__Column4_|
|            |              |          |
|..FLOOR...  |DREAMS - FLY  |  1994    |
| ..dreams   |    xyz       | floor    |
```

**Attention:** this is not a OR function `abc OR cde`
This is my php code but AND don't work like as I expect:

```
static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
    {
        $globalSearch = array();
        $columnSearch = array();
        $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

        if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
            $str = $request['search']['value'];

            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch[] = "".$column['db']." LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
        }
```

To dispel any doubts on what I want: [LOOK](http://datatables.altervista.org/Tutorials/php.htm)

This is an example picture of that I want

[image: extended AND]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

For this type of search, you might consider a full text index.  The documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  These implement the `MATCH . . . AGAINST` functionality.

With such functionality, you can order the results by relevance.  This means that you do not have to decide in advance whether the connector is "and" or "or" between multiple words.  You can also implement a boolean search, which would allow for more complex complex logic, if you so desire.

Comment: In [THIS](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf1/examples/server_side/simple_fulltext.html) example I set full text index but if I type `floor fly` it works like a pure OR condition and returns too many records, I want, simply, filter like in this table. [I wish this AND condtion](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf_client/127.0.0.1/yadcf/dimensioni%20corrette%20importante%20anche%20css%20yadcf%20filter%20-%20css.html) Look the difference.However to set OR condition in full text index I use this code but I don't like it `$globalSearch[] = "match(".$column['db'].") against (".$binding.")";`

Comment: @user3520363 . . . Are you aware that `fly` is shorter than the default minimum word length (of 4)?  So it is ignored in the search string altogether.  In addition, to get the ordering by relevance, you need to use `order by`.

Comment: I don't understand if solution is fulltext index, can you check [HERE](http://datatables.altervista.org/Tutorials/php.htm) to dispel any doubt, please? For the moment word length is not my first concern. I try to solve this later

Answer (score 0):

well, you should decide what search criteria you want to use.
If you want you use match by certain phrase, and do not want to use FULL TEXT search, you should rebuild your query like:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col1 REGEXP 'text1|text2|text3' OR a.col2 REGEXP 'text1|text2|text3';
```

In your PHP code, it should be smth like this (you did not specify input data format, so I assume, you are using "$str" as space separated text, and want to check all words in "$str" phrase for search:

```
if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
   $str = str_replace(" ","|",$str);
   $binding = self::bind( $bindings, $str, PDO::PARAM_STR );
   $globalSearch[] = "".$column['db']." REGEXP ".$binding;
}
```

Comment: I replace with your code but your php code works like OR function. For example If I type  `felino fly` table returns all rows with `felino` word and all rows with `fly` word. I want concatenate function so when I type I want display only rows with BOTH words. Can you fix it, please?