# php - AND with two condition

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I use a jquery datatables in server side processing. I try to implement in php a function for my Global Filter:

[image: global filter]

Function should display all rows only **if and only if**:

--> both words are in the same column AND *in the same row*

OR
--> both words are in different columns AND *in the same row*

So..If I type `floor free` or `floor free` on *Global Filter* it should returns always the SAME query.

You can test Global Filter here: [EXAMPLE](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf_client/127.0.0.1/yadcf/dimensioni%20corrette%20importante%20anche%20css%20yadcf%20filter%20-%20css.html)

But unfortunately this jquery table don't load data from MySQL so I need to replicate this in php (server side)

For server side processing relevant php code for Global Filter is:

```
static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
    $globalSearch = array();
    $columnSearch = array();
    $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

    if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
        $str = $request['search']['value'];

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                //$globalSearch[] = "match(".$column['db'].") against (".$binding.")";
                $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont think you will get a difference answer, the problem is still the same as in your first question regarding this issue -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/29728752/1407478. You are mixing / confusing server side filtering with client side filtering and vice verca. You'll need to choose if you want to use client side filtering or server side filtering. I lean to the conclusion that you want client side filtering, but not sure - you have only showed serverside code and screenshots telling us that the filtering is done clientside - so far I mean.

Comment: is possible or not replicate global filter like client side in php?