# MySQL order by relevance while having multiple like

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like

```
column
---------------------
his name is yyy   
What is your name  
my name is xxx
```

If I had to search for words containing "What" & "Name" while using "like" and "OR" function, I would get the results but no order.
How do I make the result containing both the words come first, and then any order

Comment: Can you show the expected output. I think your question is unclear.

Comment: What is your name  --> As this sentence contains both what & name... followed by the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a union for it:

```
select column from table where column like ('%What%') and column like ('%name%')
union
select column from table where (column like ('%What%') or column like ('%name%')) and column not in (select column from table where column like ('%What%') and column like ('%name%'))
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I wanted.... Now when I have more words, is there a simpler way to take care of all possible combinations.... other than generating a statement like this using  recursion/loops??

Comment: @KarthikShetty Not that i know at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand about your question, you want the results ordered by alphabetical order. You can [order results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) easily with the `ORDER BY` clause, such as `SELECT * FROM tblExample ORDER BY name`.

Unless you meant to ask something else of course, in which case I'd ask you to clarify your question so I can update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:
    SELECT * FROM table
    Where...
    ORDER BY FIELD(like ('[what]*[name]*') and like )
    DESC, name, alias_column;

Answer (score 0):

With your are using text for search its convenient to use MATCH AGANIST (you must set the colum with FULLTEXT index)

Then you can use the sintaxis as described in this thread:
[MATCH AGANIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column)