# Intelligent Search Using Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, match

I have an SQL table called `products_list` containing details of products, i could list out two of the very important fields here, based on which i need to integrate the INTELLECT SEARCH RESULT.

1. `product_id`
2. `product_title`

***Example of content within***

1. Lenovo K3 Note
2. Lenovo ZUK
3. Apple Iphone 6s
4. Lenovo A6000

and so on.

***What i require?***

if user enters `lenov`, it should result with `'lenovo k3 Note, lenovo zuk, lenovo a6000'`

if user enters `le`, it should result with `'lenovo k3 Note, lenovo zuk, lenovo a6000, apple iphone 6s'`

if user enters `6 iphon`, it should result with `'apple iphone 6s'`

> **NOTE:** very importantly i need most matching product to list first, Eg, if user enters `lenov zu`, the result should sort by most matched
>   string here like, 'lenovo zuk **first**, *lenovo a6000 and lenovo k3
>   **in any order***'

***What i tried?***

i tried using `'like'`, which almost worked but failed to sort with most matched string.
`select * from product_list where product_title like '%$searchString%' order by product_title asc`

i tried using `'MATCH AGAINST'` logic, this worked but failed to sort again.

```
select *, MATCH(product_title) AGAINST ('$searchString*') AS RELEVANCE from product_list where MATCH(product_title) AGAINST ('$searchString*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by RELEVANCE DESC
```

`RELEVANCE` is always 0

> **NOTE:** i have used `MyISAM` as Storage Engine, and added `FULLTEXT
>   INDEX` to the field `product_title`

Comment: What does it mean? `this worked but failed to sort again.`.  `MATCH AGAINST` is the proper method for this purpose

Comment: yup i tried it @MarcosPérezGude, but didn't get the proper result here, i tried searching 'lenov zu', it listed lenovo k3 first.

Comment: What if you print `RELEVANT` variable to see how punctuation gives each result? Maybe can be useful for us (to help you)

Comment: Are the fields setting up with `FULLTEXT` key?

Comment: yup, i have indexed the field with full text,

Comment: And why it's searching `IN BOOLEAN MODE` ? And for what is the `*` in the variable? `('$searchString*')`. I don't understand that statement. I use match against without boolean mode and without wildcard and it was working fine always.

Comment: `*` is to search substrings within the full text, Eg, field value is 'lenovo k3', you can get result by only entering 'leno'.

Comment: If you remove `*` and search `leno` it must shows `lenovo k3` too

Comment: This might will help you. It is best explained here.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6305108/4819200

Comment: Will you please guide me through, by adding up an SQL string, which I can try out. `*` is used here, because `match against` requires more than 4 chars as input. If * is used it accepts even 1 char.