# How to make a FULLTEXT search with ORDER BY fast?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to get a simple FULLTEXT match to be faster when using order by on another column on a table with over 100 million rows. Is it possible to make a FULLTEXT with an order by on another indexed column fast? SQL Fiddle below with schema and explains of all queries:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed646c/1

What I have so far is denormalization and a join but this requires a separate table and I would rather not have another table if not necessary. SQL Fiddle below (denormalized query at the end):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aabf/8

I'm open to schema changes or, if I have to, a full search engine on top.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259647/mysql-match-against-order-by-relevance-and-column

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to order it by relevance

Comment: I see that only 2 rows would be the result in your test case; how many in the real data?

Comment: If you say your first query is insanely fast: do you always use `limit 5`? Check your query without the limit (e.g. try a `count(*)`) and without the order. This is the minimum time your query needs if you order by anything else than relevancy - because it has to find all rows in the full text index, not just any random 5 first resutls. The time it requires to order and access the complete data from the table depend on the number of found rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two copies of the same data; you can "self join" for the "denormalized" case.