# exact search and similar search combining two tables with multiple keywords mysql

Tags: mysql, search

Say I've two tables products and brands having below data.

```
tbl_products            
ID  Name               BrandID    Price
1   Keyboard             1        100
2   Keyboard             2        120
3   Keyboard wireless    1        130
4   Keyboard wireless    2        150

tbl_brands  
ID  Name
1   Microsoft
2   Dell
3   HP
```

What I want is when I type 'Microsoft Keyboard' or 'Keyboard Microsoft' then it should list me product ID 1 and 3 not 2 or 4 even 2 or 4 has keyboard. I may search for more keywords but it should give me only the items matching itself.

```
SELECT p.*, b.Name BrandName FROM tbl_products p INNER JOIN tbl_brands b ON b.ID = p.BrandID WHERE p.Name LIKE '%Microsoft%' OR b.Name LIKE '%Microsoft%' OR p.Name LIKE '%Keyboard%' OR b.Name LIKE '%Keyboard%'
```

Please help me to write proper MySQL query or any schema change with query..

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: @Strawberry added the query

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759580/how-to-implement-a-keyword-search-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate the question.  Though I don't have exact answer but surely can discuss one approach to solve the problem.

**STEP 1** Get BRAND NAME+NAME as single string.

**STEP 2** Tokenise the entered STRING. Example Microsoft Keyboard = Mincrosoft,Keyboard Following Link for spliting the entered data. [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

**STEP 3** DO a like query on the string obtained in step 1.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_products p INNER JOIN gm_brands b ON b.ID = p.BrandID WHERE CONCAT(p.Name, ' ', b.Name) LIKE '%Microsoft%'
        OR CONCAT(p.Name, ' ', b.Name) LIKE '%keyboard%' tried this but no luck