# How to implement a keyword Search for specific words in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, keyword

I have a table called BIO with some biological description that I want to query for keywords in mysql.
For example I want to query for "LTR", so I used the code:

```
select * from BIO where info LIKE '%LTR%';
```

The result was:

```
id  info
1   Adenylate isopentenyltransferase       
2   Glycosyltransferase         
3   LTR element
4   Non-LTR retroelement
5   Putative non-LTR 
6   Histone LTR element
```

I also used as suggested in another question ([How to implement a Keyword Search in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759580/how-to-implement-a-keyword-search-in-mysql)) to avoid some issues:

```
SELECT * FROM BIO WHERE info LIKE CONCAT('%','LTR','%');
```

And the result was the same.

I do NOT want a result like in the first 2 lines, for example:
Glycosy**ltr**ansferase

I would like to have:

```
id  info
3   LTR element
4   Non-LTR retroelement
5   Putative non-LTR 
6   Histone LTR element
```

How is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  But for your examples, the following will work:

```
select *
from BIO
where concat(' ', replace(info, '-', ' '), ' ') LIKE '% LTR %';
```

What is the logic?  It places a space at the beginning and end of `info` and replaces all hyphens with spaces.  For the examples in your question, the occurrence of LTR that you want would then be " LTR ".

Note:  You could also work on a regular expression to do the same thing.  But it is tricky with the word boundaries and the matches at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Great suggestion. Is it possible to add to this query also something to get also "Histone/LTR" or "LTR/anything"? I forgot to include this in my question.

Comment: It worked with this one - select * from BIO where concat(' ', REPLACE(REPLACE(info, '-', ' ') , '/', ' '), ' ') LIKE '% LTR %';